# UITableView (inside VC), constraints for all device sizes?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview, autolayout

I'm having an issue using Xcode 8.1 that I haven't had before. I have a UITableView inside a ViewController and have pinned it using constraints to top (0), left (0), right (0) and bottom (0).

When I've done this before the table view expands and contracts so is always centred on all screen sizes.........but please see the screenshot for my current results.

[image: Screenshot]

I've tried removing all constraints associated with that view and trying "Reset to Suggested Constraints" but that didnt change anything and have also attempted to build all the constraints back in manually, but still no luck.

Any suggestions or am I missing something really obvious!

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked by running app in simulator or device?

Comment: I suggest you run and then check because XCode is frequently updated and this could be a bug.

Comment: Just in the simulator Bhavin. Do you both agree that what I've done with the constraints should work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Reset to Suggested Constraints" nearly always gives you something you *don't* want. It looks like your view at the top needs the constraints fixed first, then the tableview.

The first black view should be pinned to the top, right and left sides with no width, and a height specified. The tableview should be 0 all the way around.

If that doesn't work, can you share the starboard file?